# MySQL cannot sustain , auto restart without any error

Tags: mysql, innodb

I Migrate it MySQL Databse MyISAM to InnoDB but still problem facing last 24 hours  . Its a wordpress database . When it was MyISAM i face some table crash . then i dump and create a new database and change to innoDB Engine .

```
150323 17:56:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150323 17:56:47 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    150323 17:56:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    150323 17:56:50 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 739930449
    150323 17:56:50 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    150323 17:56:50 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    150323 17:56:50 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    150323 17:56:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    150323 17:56:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.41-0+wheezy1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
    Killed
    150323 17:58:55 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
    150323 17:58:55 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
    150323 17:58:55 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150323 17:58:55 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
    150323 17:58:55 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
    150323 17:58:56 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150323 17:58:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150323 17:58:56 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
    InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
    150323 17:58:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
    InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
    InnoDB: buffer...
    150323 17:58:57  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    150323 17:58:58 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 740208077
    150323 17:58:58 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    150323 17:58:58 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    150323 17:58:58 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    150323 17:58:58 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    150323 17:58:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.41-0+wheezy1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
```

Comment: I just a bunch of notes and warnings...where is the error??

Comment: This is mysql.erro file output , Where i can find the exact error

Comment: I know what file you were looking at..if there were any errors, they would show up there...I do not see any errors and it looks like mysql opened socket fine on port 3306...SO WHAT IS your issue???

Comment: Database auto restart , and become tooo much slow , after 2 3 times restart it stop , facing that problem 24 hours passed

Comment: why is it auto restarting???

Comment: That is my question , how can i find the problem , i guess mysql makes taking lots of ram , but this problem start last 1 day . MyServer in AWS and 2GB Ram

Comment: `Version: '5.5.41-0+wheezy1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
    Killed`   ...looks like someone killed it according to the log...that would not be an auto restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like you updated versions without running mysql_update.

And several of those [Warning]s smell like an old my.cnf that needs some minor editing.

128M is ok for a "tiny" 2GB of "RAM".

Comment: Because this problem not id Database . In you project some basetring or eval code is present , which hacker sending url based request and making high process and sql crash .